# Выбор даты из строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, pcre

Есть строка, нужно взять всё до второго пробела, то есть дату.

```
2016-12-13 16:39:38 и дальше текст ...
```

Comment: `/([\d\- :]+)/`? Допилите сами, домашнее задание :)

Comment: @Other дефис можно ставить в начале символьного класса, тогда он теряет значения диапазона.

Comment: А что вообще означает дефис? не могу найти

Comment: А все понял,тут жесткое условие на дефис в дате

Comment: И поясните пожалуйста зачем нужны квадратные скобки

Comment: Можно, но почему бы и не так? Как говаривал мой старик-учитель: " - Лучше экранировать, чем недоэкранировать!" :)

Answer (score 1):

Пробуйте например так, все кроме пробела захватываем
Проверить работу https://regex101.com/r/y7QO0U/3

```
/[^ ]+ [^ ]+/
```

Либо так

```
/^([^а-яё]+)\s/i
```

Многое зависит от исходных данных, начали ли это строки, возможны ли другие варианты исходной строки.

Comment: так только дату берет